# Python RegEx only returns the first match

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I want to extract all timestamps and messages from a Whatsapp chat in Python.

The code I tried is:

```
import re


file = open("Chat Analysis\Chat.txt", "r", encoding='utf8')
text = file.readline()

pattern = r'(\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}, \d{1,2}:\d{2}.[ap]m) - (.+)'

matches = re.findall(pattern, text)

for match in matches:
    timestamp, message = match
    print(f"Timestamp: {timestamp}")
    print(f"Message: {message}\n")
```

The expected output should be something like this:

```
List = ['Timestamp1' - 'Message1', 'Timestamp2' - 'Message2', ...]
```

But I am only getting the first match as follows:

```
Timestamp: 31/12/2022, 1:36 am
Message: Messages and calls are end-to-end encrypted. No one outside of this chat, not even WhatsApp, can read or listen to them. Tap to learn more.
```

I apologize if this is a duplicate question but I have tried `re.finditer`, `group()`, `print(matches[0])` and `print(matches[1])` as well but that didn't work.

Comment: what do you think that `text = file.readline()` does? it only reads the first line of the file

Answer (score -1):

your code `text = file.readline()` ohly read one line
if you want to read all data,you should use `text=file.read()`
and remeber close your file.`file.close()`

Comment: Thank you for the help!
Still it returned data for past 1 month, while I have data since 31/12/2022 in the text file.